# Is it wrong to define $-1 \circ -1 = -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem:**
Quaternions are a set of objects that are an extension of imaginary numbers except that there are three of them $i$, $j$ and $k$, with the relations
    \begin{align*}
    i^{2} = j^{2} = k^{2} = ijk = -1
\end{align*}
Construct the smallest group possible that contains all the quarternions.

**My Solution**:
Closure of the group requires that at least, $i,j,k$ and $-1$ to be the members of the group.
            Since $i^2 = i \circ i = -1$, $i$ can't be the identity of the group. Similarly $j$ and $k$ can't be identity of the group. That leaves $-1$ as the only candidate for the identity of the group. If we can satisfy other requirement of group, then $i,j,k$ and $-1$ will form a group with $-1$ as the identity.

If we define $-1 \circ -1 = -1$, which doesn't violate any of the given requirements, $-1$, works as the identity element.

Since $i^2 = i \circ i = -1$ and $-1$ is identity, $i$ by definition becomes the inverse of itself. Similarly $j$ and $k$ are inverses of themselves.
            So the group is 
            \begin{align*}
            G \left( \left\lbrace -1,i,j,k \right\rbrace, \circ \right)
        \end{align*}

**Question**: If all we are given is the statement on problem is it wrong to define $-1 \circ -1 = -1$ for this problem?

Comment: I think the issue is how "extension of the imaginary numbers" (in the statement of the problem) is to be understood. I think the intention was that the $-1$ mentioned in the problem should be the same $-1$ that you get by squaring the imaginary number $i$, and this $-1$ is not its own square. But that intention is not made clear enough in the problem as you've quoted it. So, in the absence of any additional clarification of the intention, I think one can argue that your answer is right. (Whoever posed the question should be embarrassed but might get angry instead.)

Comment: For imaginary numbers, $i^3 \ne i$, so $-1 = i^2$ cannot be the identity.

Comment: if $i$ is in the group then so is $i, i^2, i^3$ and $i^4, i^4 = 1$ and 1 is your identity.

Comment: IMO, the question statement is very badly phrased: customarily, every $a + bi + cj + dk$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ is considered a quaternion, so there can be no group containing all quaternions and extending the multiplication operation, since the cancellation law doesn't hold (for example $0 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot i$).  On the other hand, quaternions with addition already form a group.

Comment: Might be the case that it was intended to ask "what is the smallest group containing *these* (meaning i,j,k) quaternions?"

Comment: Maybe it is the [Quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group)?

Answer (score 1):

As a teacher, I interpret the question as “What is the smallest subset of the ring of quaternions that contains $i$, $j$, $k$, and $-1$, and is a group under quaternionic multiplication?” I agree with the commenters that what is written is not the same thing.

Let us call this group $G$ for short.

> Closure of the group requires that at least, $i,j,k$ and $-1$ to be the members of the group.

Yes.  But the closure can, and usually does, contain more than the elements used to define it.

> Since $i^2 = i \circ i = -1$, $i$ can't be the identity of the group. Similarly $j$ and $k$ can't be identity of the group.

Indeed, identity elements are idempotents, so you are right that these non-idempotents can't be the identity.

> That leaves $-1$ as the only candidate for the identity of the group.

Here is where I think your logic breaks down. Nobody said that $i$, $j$, $k$, and $-1$ were the *only* elements of $G$.  Any product of elements of $G$ must also be in $G$.  So the group has to contain $i^3=-i$ and $i^4=1$ as well.

There are a few more quaternions that must be in $G$.  Can you find them?

Comment: "Nobody said that $i,j,k$ and $-1$ were the only elements", but it said "smallest possible group". "Any product of elements of $G$ must be in $G$", sure, the way constructed, $i^3 = i$ and $i^4 = -1$ and so on.

Comment: “smallest possible group containing...” implies that the group operation is the one inherited from the containing set.  So it contains $i$, $j$, $k$, $-1$, and any multiplicative combinations of these, and any inverses of these, and so on.  I have never written a problem using that phrase that expected the solver to install a different operation.